# Flex/Spring/Hibernate validation - spring Validator and ExceptionTranslator

Tags: spring, dao, validation

I'm beginner in mentioned technologies and forgive me if I ask some dumb questions.

I have design problem with validation code in my app. Very often i break the DRY principle. Besides, validation confuses me somehow. I always questioning myself where to put some validation stuff, checked vs unchecked, what to propagate, what to validate etc. Still, there are some topics about mentioned stuffs, so i will concentrate on my specific problem with F/S/H technologies.

For example, my DAO **save** method have following validation:

```
public void save(Person p){  
    if(p==null) throw IllegalArgumentException("Person object is required...");
    //...
}
```

Exactly the same validation i also have in delete, update and read methods in DAO layer.

I was looking for some solution with *com.springframework.validation.Validator* interface, but I bump in to problem with propagation of error codes to Flex client.
Maybe, i could do something like this...

```
public void save(Person p){
    BeanPropertyBindingResult err = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(p,"Errors");              
    //myValidator will be injected   
    myValidator.validate(p,err);
    //...
    throw MyException("Message",err);
    //...
}
```

I don't know if this is good approach.  What validation approach to use to minimize repetition of such validation code. If someone can to give me some direction, hint, link, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try some Design by Contract annotation driven solution like [Contract4j](http://polyglotprogramming.com/contract4j)?